# Create ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

im new in flutter , and im trying to create a listView Like this photo in my app:
[image: Description flutter]

this is my code :

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Container(
                child: const Text(
                  ':الآن',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 4,
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Card(
                  semanticContainer: true,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  elevation: 5,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/aire.jpeg',
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                )),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 4,
              
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Container(
                child: const Text(
                  ':آخر الأخبـار',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**My probleme** is when i use the ListView.builder , Or ListTitle , all the views in the top disappear.
how can i solve it , Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `ListView` with `Expanded` to get available height inside column.

```dart
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
    .....
          Expanded(
             child: ListView( ...
```